# C# Simple DataSocket Example Needed

Tags: c#, sockets

I am new to C# Socket programming.  I am trying to build a simplistic application that can detect when a client application connects to the server application.
When connected, I want to send 1 piece of information to the server and receive 1 response back (confirmation).
Afterwards, I just want to know when the connection is broke.  Within my application, I do not have to know instantly when the connection is broken, just within the timeout if fine.

Can someone please help me understand what I need to do to accomplish this.  Sample source code would be nice, again I am a novice programmer and this topic is way above my head.
I would need help with the client app and server app.

Thanks in advance!

Jorel

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?  Help us HELP YOU!

Answer (score 1):

I would not begin with sockets if I were a novice programmer. It's not an easy subject to start with, and you need to know more than just how to send a piece of information. You need to know how the protocols work too and how do deal with their way of send/receiving information.

I would recommend you to use wcf instead, since WCF takes care of all lower level details for you. You will just need to know how to send and receive information.